# Transform type keys to union with optional parameters

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-typings, union-types

Is there a way type to transform the `Screens` type into `ScreensNew` type?

What I want to do is:

- Transform all first level keys into strings (like `keyof`)
- Keep the other parameters as is (strip undefined)
- Make a union type of each property afterwards

```js
type Screens = {
  First: undefined;
  Second: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

```js
type ScreensNew =
  | "First"
  | "Second": { name: string; }
}
```

Comment: Your desired type is not a valid Ts type, Do you mean something like `type ScreensNew =
  | { type: "First" }
  | { type: "Second",  name: string; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type in your post is not a valid TS type. We can create a discriminated union of the form `type ScreensNew =   | { type: "First" }   | { type: "Second",  name: string; }`:

```
type Screens = {
  First: undefined;
  Second: {
    name: string;
  }
}

type CreateDiscriminatedProps<T> = T extends undefined ? {} : T
type CreateDiscriminated<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: { type: P } & CreateDiscriminatedProps<T[P]>
}

type ScreensNew = CreateDiscriminated<Screens>

//Same as
// type ScreensNew = {
//     First: {
//         type: "First";
//     };
//     Second: {
//         type: "Second";
//     } & {
//         name: string;
//     };
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgJwhAdgZygXigbwFBRQBiAlgmsAFxQCuKAJhAGYkoT0DcBsEcA9g2r5ChFAEMAthGoUErAOZdCAXzyq8oSFADCSMcAgAREmkQkJrfewAKCPmDQAeACoA+LFGdQIADwMMMOkYWNnooAH5cZShqZw1waF0IK2NTOQtxA3oXd2xhKABtayhWKABrCBA+Jk8AXSEoTWkoYuiAMh09A1SzDKt6W3snZyLa1zU8eK14JFQ0ADkIAHcPJJSTXsssxxnkdHG8AHpDmEloMTQjw8aE2EQ9heWPfGORQlJyKlwrt9+m6gARB8KACuK83sowdc3jBeAJ6EIfr8RP8oADYfwGKCkSJ2t9wcioOIpDJgHIUIocSooVBlEA)

Comment: Oh yes, you are absolutely right. Totally missed that this is not a valid type. But your answer is nonetheless helpful. Thanks :)